# Select All onclick on checkbox along with reject all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me with the checkbox select all option.
I need to check all the checkboxes when i click on the checkbox. and reject all when i click on the reject check.

I am thrown with a scenario of i have to choose only one option from each columns either accept or reject. the user should not be able to choose both acceppt and reject.

and there are multiple tables in the page and generating a dynamic id i am looping through a foreach to generate those tables for each user.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>score</th>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Reviewer</th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Accept<input type="checkbox" id="AcceptAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Reject<input type="checkbox" id="RejectAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>score</th>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Reviewer</th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Accept<input type="checkbox" id="AcceptAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Reject<input type="checkbox" id="RejectAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/iamsrk/7mgcncnk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always Make sure that you give a unique id to in the whole document

In your case `#AcceptAll` is repeated because of the loop you are using.
So use class for that.

The code is ok jush replace id with a class

```
<input type="checkbox" id="AcceptAll" name="checkbox">
to
<input type="checkbox" class="AcceptAll" name="checkbox">
```

and in jquery use this

```
$(".AcceptAll")
```

Check this out

```js
$(".AcceptAll").bind("change", function () {
   $(this).closest("table").find(".Reject").prop("checked", false);
            $(this).closest("table").find(".Accept").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        });

        $(".RejectAll").bind("change", function () {
         $(this).closest("table").find(".Accept").prop("checked", false);
            $(this).closest("table").find(".Reject").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        });

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>score</th>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Reviewer</th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Accept<input type="checkbox" class="AcceptAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Reject<input type="checkbox" class="RejectAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>Agency</th>
<th>score</th>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Reviewer</th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Accept<input type="checkbox" class="AcceptAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
<th class="text-center"><label>Reject<input type="checkbox" class="RejectAll" name="checkbox"></label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>srara</td>
<td>rfara</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>fafaf</td>
<td>rara</td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Accept" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="Reject" name="checkbox" value="value"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.. But, when i select the accept and reject all both the boxes are getting selected. I have to select only one in each rows. Which is the main issue i am having

Comment: Have you checked that https://jsfiddle.net/7mgcncnk/1/ its behaving ok. 
If you still have problem then update your code so we can have a look into it

Comment: yeah i did. sorry for not explaining properly. The issue is I should be selecing only one option either accept or reject. Is you click on both the checkboxes all are slected which shouldn't happen.

Comment: I am posting the userdata and i should have only one value either the user is accepted or rejected but not both for each column

Comment: Ok sorry i just cant understand that. I am on it

Comment: @Ramki Please update the question with all relevant requirements.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i updated the question. Sorry for the confusion. aman helped me in pointing the mistake i did by declaring class rather than id. But, The issue i am left with is choosing only checkbox either accept or reject as the user should not be allowed to choose both the checkboxes from both the columns for each row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check now hope this is what you are expecting